# Is it possible to have number of locks greater than number of buckets in ConcurrentHashMap in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, concurrenthashmap

As we know, java's ConcurrentHashMap has a number of internal locks, and each of them guards some region of the bucket's array.

public ConcurrentHashMap(int initialCapacity,
                         loat loadFactor,
                         int concurrencyLevel)

initialCapacity: 16;
loadFactory: 0.75f;
concurrencyLevel: 16.

i.e Default concurrencyLevel and initialCapacity is same.

Is is possible to have more no. of locks than no. of buckets ?

Answer (score 0):

No, the CHM uses each bucket as a lock (before Java 7 each bucket was a `ReentrantLock` now each bucket will `synchronized`. So by definition, there cannot be more locks.